# Use “name” query string to refer to form field instead of pagename

Tags: query-string

I’m trying to auto-populate a form using url parameters (query strings). The problem is when I use the “name” query string (eg mysite.com/?name=xyz), it is referring to the pagename instead of the Name form field and showing a 404 error.

For eg, if I type mysite.com/?name=david, it shows 404 but if I type mysite.com/?name=about it goes to mysite.com/about.

To try and override this on the page where I have the form, I tried the following code:

```
function del_name ($qvar) {
    if ( is_page( 'page-slug' ) ) {
        function is_name( $var ) {
            return $var !== 'name';
        }
        $qvar = array_filter($qvar, 'is_name', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    }
    return $qvar;
}
add_action( 'query_vars', 'del_name' );
```

But this isn't working. I'd really appreciate if someone can fix my code.

PS: I need the name query string for an api integration and I understand that this might break the permalink structure but I want to try it out and see if the trade off is worth it

Comment: I can't really think of an API integration which would require you to use a specific GET querystring variable for a form submission - could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: So the app I'm trying to integrate calls a url with pre-set querystrings every time my listing on the app receives a new lead. One of the pre-set querystrings is name. For example, say John whose contact no is 123 enquired for abc, the app calls mywebsite.com?name=john&phone=123&product=abc. To capture the leads I'm using a form that autosubmits and I need to be able to capture the name as well

Comment: Gotchya! That's a prime use-case for [a custom REST route](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) - they're not too tricky to register, and the REST API interface was designed for data exchange. Since REST routes are not a part of the visual front-end of the site presented to visitors in their browsers, it does not attempt to map incoming query vars into the main query. Would be like `mywebsite.com/wp-json/david/v1/webhook-thingy?name=john&phone=123&product=abc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When handling form submissions, it would generally be advisable to POST your form to [a custom AJAX handler](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or [`wp-admin/admin-post.php` form handler](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_nopriv_action/). If an external API integration requires you to accept the `name` parameter, setting up this functionality as a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) endpoint or controller would give you fairly complete control over the query vars.

That said, you can use the `request` filter to remap incoming querystring variables. In this case, I would recommend reassigning `name`'s value to something else internally so as to not break anything else or require any other hacky work-arounds.

Most "pretty permalink" permastructs will map the URI `/myslug` to the `pagename=myslug` query var key/value. That in mind, we can re-assign `name` for your page as such:

```php
function wpse391078_remap_myslug_page_name_var( $qvs ) {
  if( ! empty( $qvs['pagename'] ) && $qvs['pagename'] === 'myslug' ) {
    $qvs['wpse391078_name'] = $qvs['name'];
    unset( $qvs['name'] );
  }

  return $qvs;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse391078_remap_myslug_page_name_var' );
```